# Create Geo IP from CSV file - Logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I need to input a csv file to logstash , Filter out source IP field and convert it to geoip. My kibana message is like this now :

```
June 29th 2016, 12:22:07.194    message:"Jun 27, 2016, 10:56:17 PM",107.77.212.114,10.119.1.29,HTTP 200 - Ok,CTSUSCHDSXCM003,1 @version:1 @timestamp:June 29th 2016, 12:22:07.194 path:/mnt/shiny/ELT.csv host:ubuntuserver _id:AVWa7d0P6YdQaT-CDTqx _type:logs _index:elt1 _score:
```

Can someone help me with logstash config file to achieve the same.

I have tried:

```
input{
    file{
    path=> "/mnt/shiny/ELT.csv" start_position=>"beginning" }
}

filter{ 
    csv{
        columns => ["Start Time","Source IP","Destination IP","Event Name","Log Source","Event Count"] separator=>"," 
    }
    geoip {
        source => "Source IP" 
        target => "geoip" 
        database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat" 
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ] 
        add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ] 
    }
    mutate {
        convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"] 
    }                 
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts=>"localhost:9200" 
        index=>"elt1" 
    }
}
```

Comment: input{
file{
path=> "/mnt/shiny/ELT.csv"
start_position=>"beginning"
}}
filter{
csv{
columns => ["Start Time","Source IP","Destination IP","Event Name","Log Source","Event Count"]
separator=>","
}
geoip {
 source => "Source IP"
  target => "geoip"
   database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
   add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
   add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
    }
   mutate {
      convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
}
 }
output{
elasticsearch{
hosts=>"localhost:9200"
index=>"elt1"
}
}

Comment: @shrirambharath please edit your original question and add your configuration formatted as this is hard to decipher

Comment: And what does not work with your configuration: Error message? Output not corresponding to what is expected?

Comment: Error message is too long and it goes on like "An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument - Invalid file>, :class=>"Errno::EINVAL", :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1807:in `seek'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/geoip-1.6.1/lib/geoip.rb:543:in `detect_database_type!'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/geoip-1.6.1/lib/geoip.rb:237:in `initialize'", " I am expecting to add geoip field in my elasticsearch.

Comment: You should add the information in your question, it would be easier to read.

Comment: It look like a problem with your geoip database file.

Comment: There may be a problem with your geoip database, but it also looks as though your csv filter is not working either

Comment: Any comments on how to fix it.

Comment: First you'll have to fix your csv filter: it won't work since you have **,** in your data. Either you change the separator in your file, or you use a grok filter. And have you check your geoip database? It has to be a legacy database

Answer (score 0):

Baudsp,Will your responses are correct. The database is the issue i fixed by downloading a new one. Thanks for your help.